# Animating WPF DataGrid IsSelected creating memory leaks

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, datagrid

I have a WPF application where I have DataGrid with 4 rows. I have a DataTrigger to animate the selection using BeginStoryBoard. Each selection change creates a heap of memory leak. It is so weird.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock" 
                                                       To="375" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock"
                                                       To="375" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock" 
                                                       To="1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock"
                                                       To="300" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock"
                                                       To="300" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="valueTextBlock" 
                                                       To="0.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.4"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource brushTextBox_Border_Focused}" TargetName="valueTextBlock" />
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
```

This is done on the DataTemplate. And also Storyboard is added to the DataGridCell style to increase the FontSize when row selected. I am sure, I have done the animation not in a proper way. But when I tried to use RemoveStoryBoard, the animation is not smooth.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest u go with your Animation.But what u can do is you can Lower the framerate of animations by setting Storyboard.DesiredFrameRate to lower the CPU load. The default is 60 frames/second.I would suggest you go with reducing the above frame Rate between 10-30.

Comment: @AshokRathod as a matter of fact, I did. Its not much, I am gaining... I also added RemoveStoryboard, the memory gained is not at all releasing...

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, you must call the Garbage Collector because StoryBoards have a big bug. try this before load "imagen":

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: I don't think, this is a solution. And this solve a thing in this scenario.